# Can't find a way to import VDB files from Embergen to Blender for Octane

Tags: octane-render-engine

I've exported a fire sim as VDB files from Embergen, and want to import them into Blender to be rendered with Octane.

Following a tutorial, the guy said to go *Object Data > Octane Properties > Volume > Use object for OctaneVDB*, but I don't have a *Volume* tab in there. I've also tried following other tutorials but they use Cycles so of course does not work.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Volume > Import OpenVDB*. If it's the Nvidia Studio Tut the rest is pretty close. Except just check sequence instead of adding dollar sign 4F dollar sign to file location.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).